# Android custom component not preserving state right

Tags: java, android, components, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view

I have 4 custom compound components in a layout, each extends from RelativeLayout.  Conceptually they're simply list rows with a title and a CheckBox.  I want each component to preserve it's own checked state.  Unfortunately they somehow seem to be sharing their state, i.e. after a config change the checked state of all four is dictated by whether or not only the last one in the layout was checked.  I did some logging and found that onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState are both being called twice per each uniquely id'd row.

I would appreciate any help, this is baffling

```
private int NOT_CHECKED = 0;
private int IS_CHECKED = 1;
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
    ss.checked = mCheckBox.isChecked() ? IS_CHECKED : NOT_CHECKED;
    Log.e("Active", "Out - " + this.getId() + " - " + mCheckBox.isChecked());
    return ss;
} 
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if(!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        return;
    }
    SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
    mCheckBox.setChecked(ss.checked == IS_CHECKED ? true : false);
    Log.e("Active", "In - " + this.getId() + " - " + mCheckBox.isChecked());
}


private static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
private int checked;

SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
    super(superState);
}
private SavedState(Parcel in) {
    super(in);
    this.checked = in.readInt();

}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(out, flags);

    out.writeInt(this.checked);
}
public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<FilterCheckBoxRow.SavedState>() {

    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new SavedState(in);
    }
    public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SavedState[size];
    }

};
```

}